# Exported file not present in the directory - R

Tags: r

I'm trying to export my graph from RStudio using the sg_export_svg function of the sigmajs library. The code runs with no error but the graph is not exported into my directory. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

```
nodes_dyn <- sg_get_layout(nodes_dyn, edge_dyn)

nodes_dyn <- sg_get_cluster(
  nodes_dyn, 
  edge_dyn,
  colors = c(
    "#0084b4",
    "#00aced",
    "#1dcaff",
    "#c0deed", 
    "#32CD32"
    )
  )

sigmajs() %>% 
  sg_add_nodes(nodes_dyn, start, id, label, size, color, cumsum = FALSE) %>% 
  sg_add_edges(edge_dyn, created_at, id, source, target, cumsum = FALSE)  %>% 
  sg_settings(
    edgeColor = "default",
    defaultEdgeColor = "#d3d3d3"
  ) %>% sg_export_svg(download = TRUE, file = "trial.svg", labels = TRUE) %>% 
  sg_button("export_svg", "download")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `dev.off ()` or restart R program. Be sure from work directory using `getwd()`

Comment: I've tried to do both but the file is still not present in the working directory. The code runs without an error message though.

Comment: I'm able to export the file using R so I'm assuming the issue is with RStudio. Thanks for your help!